# Play Framework 2.3 run driver specific evolutions

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, h2, playframework-evolutions

In local development and in test I am using an in memory h2 driver. In production I am using a postgresql driver. Im having issues where i need to run a evolution query just for postgresql. Is there some way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll rather suggest to use more appropriate tool to deal with database evolution/migration.

checkout http://flywaydb.org/